# Problemas para extraer información de pagina web externa

Tags: php, html5, web, curl, hosting

tengo un script en php que me lee un archivo .csv, extrae la información que contiene y uno de los datos que extrae lo utiliza a su vez para consultar una ruta externa(otra pagina web) y extraer de esta una información. Esto se suele realizar dentro de un bucle while debido a que son bastantes datos los extraídos del archivo. 
La cuestión es que el script anda muy bien cuando cargo un archivo que posee poquitos datos a analizar, para ser más especifico, menos de 20 datos. Pero cuando el archivo .csv contiene muchos más entonces el script no anda del todo bien ya que el dato que me debe generar desde la ruta externa no lo genera.

Ejemplo:
digamos que tengo un primer script en el cual extraigo de un archivo .csv una lista de correos electronicos y unos ID's entonces uso a su vez una funcion (dentro de este script) que hace una consulta a una pagina web externa y se le pasa como parametro cada ID que extraigo del archivo .csv y me debe dar como resultado un nombre, todo esto se hace dentro de un bucle while.
Pero lo que sucede es que cuando son muchos ID la función que me permite generar los nombres no funciona para nada bien porque no me extrae ningún nombre. Ahora, si son pocos ID, por ejemplo unos 10 o 20 ID's entonces la función si me genera los nombres. 
He revisado de arriba hacia abajo el codigo y todo esta bien, pues si cargo un archivo de pocos datos si anda todo perfecto. 
Entonces no se por qué sucede esto. Los archivos están subidos en servidor pago. A mi script también le coloque al inicio un set_time_limit(0); para tratar el limite de tiempo de 30 segundos y de hecho no me sale ese error que al principio si me salia. Pero no entiendo por qué no me extrae los nombres. Mi conexión a internet esta bien. No se si sea el servidor que interrumpe la conexión, no se.

Alguien qué tenga alguna idea de por qué sucede esto?

PD: Para optener la información de la pagina web externa uso la función curl

Comment: si el servidor que consultas no es tuyo, seguramente tenga límites de conexiones. prueba a darle un sleep entre cada petición o preguntar al administrador de la página que consultas si hay formas de hacer una consulta en bloque

Comment: Efectivamente el servidor que consulto mo es mio, entonces por eso tenia la duda de si era o no posible que un servidor tenga algún limite de conexión o cosas asi. Porque cuando son pocos datos va genial pero cuando son muchos no me genera nada. Entonces no se si es problema de mi servidor o del servidor que estoy consultando.

Comment: es práctica estándar sino te vuelcan el server con múltiples peticiones (o lo mas común y mundano:  te llega una factura de exceso de ancho de banda), un sleep cada n peticiones o un cron que vaya encolando pueden ser mas amables con el servidor

Comment: La idea del Cron realmente no me sirve, de hecho ese script que he creado se ejecuta por medio de cron; voy a probar colocarle un sleep de unos 20s tal vez, a ver qué pasa.

Comment: Probe colocar el sleep pero sigue igual

Comment: Podes montar una prueba con un html que haga las peticiones con ajax, de esa manera podrás ver la respuesta a una petición fallida en la consola developer (slowdown, 403/404/410, 200 pero vacío, un captcha, algun tipo de error personalizado, o un server closed conection) y a partir de ahí ver que onda (también podes meter un debug en el curl php pero el panel de network es mas visual si la respuesta es html)

Comment: vale, lo haré a ver que resultados obtengo y le comento.